# soapui ; getting result in different Testcase

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have one *groovy script* named Check in testcase 1, which contains the follow code:

```
log.info "Running from different test case script"
```

I am trying to get this message in a script written in testcase 2:

```java
package com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase; 
Test_script= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite"].testCases["TestCase"].testSteps["Check"]
def myCont= new WsdlTestRunContext(Test_script)
log.info  Test_script.run(testRunner,myCont)
```

It gives me output as:

> Wed May 18 17:39:57 IST 2016:INFO:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestStepResult@131bc813

What to do here to see proper message in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestStep.run` method doesn't return directly a desired object from other testStep or so, It returns a generic [`WsdlTestStepResult`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestStepResult.html) object to see the status, possible errors etc.. of the testStep execution, due this `log.info  Test_script.run(testRunner,myCont)` it's printing the result of `toString()` method on `WsdlTestStepResult` object.

If you want to pass objects from one *groovy script* testStep to another, you've to use the `context` variable which is available in each *groovy script* testStep.

For your case since you're running the first *groovy script* using [`TestStep.run(TestCaseRunner testRunner,TestCaseRunContext testRunContext)`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStep.html#run(com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCaseRunner,%20com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCaseRunContext)) from the second one script, you can get back all objects added in the `context` of your first script in the second one with `testRunContext` object passed to `run` method. Let me show it with an example:

In the first *groovy script* add your text as a property of the `context`:

```java
// instead of log put the text in a context property
context.setProperty('somePropToGetBack','Running from different test case script')
// you can put all the properties you want...
context.setProperty('anotherOne','more props')
```

Then in your second script you only have to get back these properties:

```java
package com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext
def Test_script= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite"].testCases["TestCase"].testSteps["Check"]
def myCont= new WsdlTestRunContext(Test_script)
def result = Test_script.run(testRunner,myCont)

// after execution in myCont variable you've all properties you set
// in context variable of first script
log.info myCont.getProperty('somePropToGetBack') // prints Wed May 18 14:56:36 CEST 2016:INFO:Running from different test case script
log.info myCont.getProperty('anotherOne') // prints Wed May 18 14:56:36 CEST 2016:INFO:more props
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was looking for the teststep.run concept. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @sunny nice to help you `:)`. You can also check all the things you've available in the [`TestStepResult`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestStepResult.html) returned from `run` method, to see if some are utils for your case.